# Multistate Survival Analysis using R package "Survival"

Tags: r, survival-analysis, cox-regression

I am trying to estimate Cox proportional hazards model for transition from state 1 to state 2 using R `survival` package as follows:

```
Altman <- coxph(Surv(Tstart, Tstop, to == 2) ~ wWCTA + wRETA + wEBITTA + wMETL + 
            wSTA, data=Multistate, subset = from == 1, 
          frailty(x=id, distribution= "gamma"))
```

When I am estimating the model without the `frailty` argument, its working fine. But when I am including it, I am getting the following error:

```
Error in if (any(ord > 1)) stop("Penalty terms cannot be in an interaction") : 
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Can anyone please explain where I am going wrong?

Regards,

J

Comment: Generally Therneau recommends using coxme for frailty models these days.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem but eventually realized that the frailty term is additive! That is, it shouldn't come after a comma but after a plus.

Changing your code to the following should thus solve the problem:

```
Altman <- coxph(Surv(Tstart, Tstop, to == 2) ~ wWCTA + wRETA + wEBITTA + wMETL + wSTA + frailty(x=id, distribution= "gamma"), data=Multistate, subset = from == 1)
```